# Facebook Graph API and app secret

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an iOS application that I'm logging to Facebook to ask for an access_token.

Then I pass this access token to my server and I want to get the '/me' information, using my  **appsecret_proof** but I noticed that I can do it **without appsecret_proof**:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=THE_ACCESS_TOKEN"

{"id":"658267751","name":"Ricardo Otero",
"first_name":"Ricardo","last_name":"Otero",
"link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/oterosantos",
"hometown":{"id":"107911285910314","name":"Coimbra, Portugal"},
"location":{"id":"110432202311659","name":"Lisbon, Portugal"}...
```

Although I have set the option "App Secret Proof for Server API calls" to true:

[image: facebook settings]

So, shouldn't the requests require the app secret? I don't get it!

Comment: By my experience, Graph API only needs the `access_token`.

Comment: @Jhn: but I want it to work only if the app secret is given, for security reasons. What if someone gets the access_token from a client?

Comment: hi, @RicardoOtero, I have the same problem, did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @JIEWANG I don't think I did. It was a long time ago, but I couldn't solve the problem this way IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every access_token depends on app and user so for different app and user combination you will have different access token so you don't need to worry. though I am no sure why are you doing it this way 
http://m-farhan.com/2014/03/ios-facebook-sdk-tutorial/
is the right way of doing this.

Comment: Because I want to send the token to the server (so I can access Facebook from there to get information) and if the token is caught by eavesdropping then malicious requests can be made!

Comment: Token is good for 60days then it expires if you really need it use ssl connection on your server and graph api is always ssl so no need to worry if you really want, you can add key hash. And once you have token you can just get all user data that token have permission of, even posting on wall if it has permission

Comment: SSL connection doesn't help you with the problem that attackers can decompile your app, extract the `appsecret_proof` and then perform Facebook calls on behalf of other users.

Comment: hyperlink in answer appears to be broken

Answer (score 0):

I am also navigating through the Facebook API "appsecret_proof" parameter -- here are the official docs on Facebook Developers Website:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof -- it looks like this example PHP call can help you out:

```
$appsecret_proof= hash_hmac('sha256', $access_token, $app_secret);
```

Here's the Example Command-Line call they display:

```
curl \
  -F 'access_token=<access_token>' \
  -F 'appsecret_proof=<app secret proof>' \
  -F 'batch=[{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me"},{"method":"GET", "relative_url":"me/friends?limit=50"}]' \
  https://graph.facebook.com
```

Here's someone who made a similar call with a Node.JS Server(dosen't look there is speciifc FACebook/API/SDK referecne though... :

[Get signed_request in Node.js (Express) Facebook canvas app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977989/get-signed-request-in-node-js-express-facebook-canvas-app)

Comment: FOLLOW UP TO ABOVE ANSWER: